# How to deal with JSON that has no names in android

Tags: android, json

I'm retrieving the following JSON from a web service:

```
 ["test_w","\u062a\u0637\u0628\u064a\u0642 \u0631\u0642\u0645 3","\u062a\u0637\u0628
 \u064a \u0642 \u0631\u0642\u0645 2","\u062a\u0637\u0628\u064a\u0642 \u0631\u0642\u0645 
 1","test_333","\u0645\u0639\u0631\u0641\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0627\u0621 \u0627\u0644
 \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637\u0629 \u0648\u062a\u0646\u0648\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644
  \u0636\u0645","\u0639\u0644\u0648\u0645","\u0648\u0631\u0642\u0629 \u0639\u0645\u0644"]
```

As you can see, it's not in name, value format; I tried accessing the JsonObject itself but it's always returning null:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(resultLine);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {                     
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            notifArray.add(json_data.toString());
```

Is there any way to deal with this particular format of JSON ?

Comment: The JSON which you have posted is not valid check here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: it was valid here and that's why i asked the question http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Just copy and paste the JSON in the website given by you and validate. it failed.. so please check for the format of JSON. Parse error on line 3:
...u0642\u0645 3",    "\u062a\u0637\u0628
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Comment: The JSON seems to have some strange whitespace. That's probably an artifact of pasting it into the question. If you replace the whitespace with valid characters, it's okay. It mainly contains arabic text.

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of strings. So you have to use `getString` (or `optString`) to access the array elements:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(resultLine);
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {                     
    String str = jArray.getString(i);
    notifArray.add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(resultLine);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {                     
            notifArray.add(jArray.get(i));
        }
```